# Code generation of TCP/IP block

Tags: simulink, tcp

I am using Simulink to simualte turning on/off leds on a hardware board. I am using the TCP/IP block provided by instrument control toolbox to communicate data between the Simulink block and the board. So my Simulink model is the client. I want to generate C code of the model but the generated code doesn't include the TCP/IP block. Do you guys have any ideas why I got this problem? Do you know how can I implement my own TCP/IP block that might be generated to c code? Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the rtw file is created in your case and you are using Simulink Coder or Real Time Workshop.

To create C-Code from specific block (as your TCP/IP-Block) you need a block specific tlc-File. 
TLC = Target Language Compiler

Taken from TLC documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/rtw/rtw_tlc.pdf

> Real-Time Workshop invokes the TLC after a Simulink model is compiled
>   into an intermediate form (model.rtw) that is suitable for generating
>   code. To generate code apropriately, the TLC uses its library of
>   functions to transform
>
> two classes of target files:
>
> •System target files
>
> •Block target files

I guess the block target file of the Tcp/Ip - Block is missing.

If you don't have it or get you have to implement the tcp/ip functionality in TLC.

(Please bear with me, I do not have privileges to add comments, yet)